# How to Login as Customer from Admin Dashboard without Customer Password?

Tags: magento2, module

I am a newbie at Magento 2 and I would like to ask how to log in as the customer on admin side.?[image]

Answer (score 1):

By default you can't do that. However there is one free module that can help you

magefan/module-login-as-customer

https://github.com/magefan/module-login-as-customer

You can try this module.